# Reactjs: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am pretty new to reactjs, I am trying to call an api data to get the response through axios. But getting the same error again and again.

**Error**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.

There are so many similar questions but I couldn't find any answer that could help me. The code I am using is given below.

**Code**

```
const token = userService.getToken();

  const api = `http://localhost:54729/api/Search?searchString=${text}`;
  axios
    .get(api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("hello" + res);
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
          payload: res.data// Dummy data
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error" + err);
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    });
```

**Edit**

The response from api is

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "example-, example- und example(CC 11): example– example Berlin",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/herz?url=https://www.example.de/example/example/example/",
        "url": "https://www.example.de/example/charitecentren/example/",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "example Klinik mit exampleKardiologie (example) - Charité – example Berlin",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/herz?url=https://example-cvk.example.de/",
        "url": "https://example-example.example.de/",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Deutsche Zentren example example: example– Universitätsmedizin example",
        "description": null,
        "owner": null,
        "link": "/search/herz?url=https://www.example.de/forschung/example/example/",
        "url": "https://www.example.de/example/example/deutsche_zentren_fuer_gesundheitsforschung/",
        "type": "External",
        "rank": 0
    },
]
```

when I `console.log(res.data)` it says `undefined`.

Also, nobody has asked me yet till now what `dispatch: FETCH_PRODUCTS` is doing really. You can see it below. May be it will help, what I am trying to do.

```
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS:
            console.log(action)
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload,
                loading: false,
                totalRecords: action.payload.length,
            };
```

Comment: can you please attach your response from the API here?

Comment: When you consoled `res` what does it show? Probably `res`doesn't have `data ` property inside.

Comment: I have edit the question again.

Comment: Is result of  `console.log(res) ` also undefined?

Comment: yes it is also undefined @octobus

Comment: Then you not getting any object from your request. Check your backend if you can see the request. Maybe you are  not sending right info there and your error handling on backend needs somework.

Comment: The backend is working pretty well, everything is ok ... It's just here on the frontend when I am trying to fetch the data it gives me this error.

Comment: I have editted the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, After thorough deep understanding of code, I came to the conclusion that we were using interceptors to pass throught the response.

the interceptor looks like this before

```
 axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        const error =
          (response.data && response.data.message) || response.statusText;
        cogoToastHelper.error(error);
        console.log("I am here in Interceptor");
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      console.log("I am here in Interceptor before cogoToast");
      cogoToastHelper.info(response.data.message);
      //return response.data.data;
      console.log("HERE RESPONSE" + response.data.data);
        return response.data.data;
```

So I changed this into the code below

```
 axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        const error =
          (response.data && response.data.message) || response.statusText;
        cogoToastHelper.error(error);
        console.log("I am here in Interceptor");
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      console.log("I am here in Interceptor before cogoToast");
      cogoToastHelper.info(response.data.message);
      //return response.data.data;
      console.log("HERE RESPONSE" + response.data.data);
      if (response.data.data !== undefined) {
        console.log("I got response.data.data");
        return response.data.data;
      } else {
        console.log("I got response.data");
        return response.data;
      }
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `res` object has no `data` object in it. Your `res` is the array which your API returns. So just executing `console.log(res)` instead of `console.log(res.data)` should do the trick.

Comment: It still has nothing in it.. even console.log(res) is undefined

Comment: My guess is that this isn't a frontend problem then, are you sure that array is the actual response you are getting from your API call? Is that call throwing any other errors?

Comment: The api in backend is working well. And Array is the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your response as a parameter in .then method see below

```
   axios
    .get(api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("hello" + res);
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
          payload: res.data// Dummy data
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error" + err);
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: No, res is undefined. I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: Also, I have editted the question once again, may be it is more easy for you to understand now

Comment: The result is same..! This is so confusing. !

Comment: @Khan this time have you got anything in `res` ? or yet it is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```js
const token = userService.getToken();

  const api = `http://localhost:54729/api/Search?searchString=${text}`;
  const resData = async()=> axios.get(api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`

try{
console.log(resData.data,"Response from api")
dispatch({type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,payload: resData.data});
}
catch(e){
 console.log("error" + err);
}
```